# Big Query - "Insert" a Query into a empty column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-insert

I would like to know what to do to insert into a column a query.

What I am doing:

**1º step - I create a column to insert the values from this query (it's working)**

```
alter table `cpj._cad_processo_copy`
add column TEST_INSERT_VALUES_FROM_QUERY string
```

**2º step - Test the query (it's working)**

```
SELECT mat.descricao as mp
FROM `cpj._cad_processo_copy` as pro
LEFT JOIN `cpj.tab_materia` as mat
ON pro.materia = mat.codigo
```

**3º step -**

```
INSERT INTO `cpj._cad_processo_copy` (TEST_INSERT_VALUES_FROM_QUERY)
SELECT mat.descricao as mp
FROM `cpj._cad_processo_copy` as pro
LEFT JOIN `cpj.tab_materia` as mat
ON pro.materia = mat.codigo
```

And nothing happens, no error... no filled column, nothing...

The length of the `cpj._cad_processo_copy` is the same of the query, 21868 lines.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need an UPDATE query, not an INSERT query.  INSERT adds new rows.  You want to modify existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use update statement as follows for 3rd Step:

```
update  `cpj._cad_processo_copy` pro
set pro.TEST_INSERT_VALUES_FROM_QUERY = mat.descricao
from  `cpj.tab_materia`  mat
where pro.materia = mat.codigo;
```